# How can I create a user that is just used for STMP authentication in Redhat 6

Tags: linux, smtp

I want to create authenticating user for SMTP on RedHat 6. When a user needs to use exim4 smtp user must be used but not for ssh or anything else.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to a) make `exim4` (and only it) run as user `smtp`, b) require the user to enter username `smtp` and some password in order to be abke to send mail through `exim4`, c) make `exim4` authenticate as user `smtp` when connecting to some other mail server, d) some combination of the previous, e) something else?

Answer (score 0):

## Some ideas

- You can use `nftables`, to block all other network access.
- You can use `apparmor`, to block use of apps. (I am not sure how effective this will be. It may block too much or too little.)
- You can use a restricted shell.